# Rendering PK instead of username in CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am building an app where managers can create a private webpage, they need to add people manually in order for them to access the page.

I don't want the managers to see all of the users, So I would like to render only the PK in the list.

**My views.py**

```
class HotelCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Hotel
form_class = HotelForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.manager_hotel = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Hotel

class ColleagueChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.get_pk()

class HotelForm(models.Model):
    ColleagueModelChoiceField(queryset=Colleague.objects.filter(pk))
```

Comment: Where is the list view?

Comment: your requirement was not clear

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta what was not clear ? 
JPG I don't want any change on the ListView, I just want the form in the **HotelCreateView** to render the PK instead of the usernames in the choice field

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information. What choice field? What usernames? Is it for the `colleague` field? Please show the Hotel model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited. The choice field is a ManyToManyField which use the user from **django.contrib.auth.models**. Yes it is for the colleague field

Comment: You have to create a modelform for the hotel model and manually change the values of the collegues to display pks  for each user instead of the username

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated my code but still there is errors

Comment: *What* errors? If you want us to help you, you need to give us the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `fields` on your `CreateView`, so you're letting Django generate the `ModelForm` automatically for you. The form uses a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which derives from `ModelChoiceField`, described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

If you read the last paragraph of that section, you'll see that the display values for such a field are coming from the model's `__str__` method, or you can override this with the `label_from_instance()` method.

That's therefore what you need to do, override this method on the `ModelMultipleChoiceField`. But to do that, you need to specify your own form.

So:

- Create your own ModelForm for your `Hotel` model (`HotelForm`).
- Create a subclass of `ModelMultipleChoiceField` (`ColleagueChoiceField`) and override the `label_from_instance()` method to display the `pk`.
- Set the `colleagues` field on the `HotelForm` to be a `ColleagueChoiceField`.
- Remove the `fields` attribute on your view and set the `form_class` to your `HotelForm` instead.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot figured it out I tried :
**forms.py** :

from django import forms 

class HotelForm(forms.Form):
    collaborateurs = forms.ColleagueChoiceField(label_from_instance('pk'))

is it good ?

Comment: You should create a ModelForm not just a Form, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/). And no, `label_from_instance()` is a method on `ModelMultipleChoiceField` so you need to subclass that first, like I said, and override the method. You need to do all 4 steps I mentioned.

Comment: @dirkgrotten, see my udpated code. I have never work with modelForm so there is probably huge mistake

Comment: You didn't read the link I proposed about a ModelForm, otherwise you'd know you have to specify `model` and `fields`. Especially [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) on how to customise the fields. The example given to change `field_classes` is exactly what you're looking for.